# Why is tryEmit not included in the FlowCollector interface?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

[MutableSharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/index.html) and [MutableStateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html) (via inheritance) include both the [emit](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/emit.html) suspend function and the best effort, non-suspend [tryEmit](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/try-emit.html). But [FlowCollector](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow-collector/index.html) only includes emit in the interface. It seems to me the there no reason why the `FlowCollector` can't provide tryEmit as well given that it's safe enough to include in `MutableSharedFlow`.

It would be useful to be able to emit into a 'collector' interface like `FlowCollector` without launching a coroutine and dealing with the lifecycle issues coming from that. So why the omission?

Comment: I suppose one simple solution to this is to just add my own wrapper for shared flow that passes through emit and tryEmit  and just add an extension function to SharedFlow to convert to it. But then I'm add my own type.

Comment: I can also just expose tryEmit as a method for the class instead of the FlowCollector.

Comment: Ok, I think the direct answer to your question is that they reused the FlowCollector interface that comes from the flow builder function, which long predates SharedFlow. That implementation is not thread-safe so they can’t backport `tryEmit` without possibly affecting performance or monkeying with a design that is already robust. I suppose they could have used a new interface instead of FlowCollector. I don’t really see a strong use case for it. The encapsulation wouldn’t increase safety, only reduce namespace clutter.